# JQuery Date Picker Vs Customized Date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a date picker which is based on Javascript and customized  by me at:

http://jsfiddle.net/premseoul/BjDYP/6/

The main problem with this date picker is I cant able to create multiple instances.

But the date picker based on jquery is working fine at:

http://jsfiddle.net/premseoul/amV5g/

I want multiple instances in the date picker which is customized by me.

Comment: You can download the the source code from http://www.4shared.com/file/ZQy2A3DU/DateTime.html
Can any help me out

Comment: If possible please share any link of date pickwer which contains multiple instanse of date picker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your .js fiddle doesn't work (won't trigger callendary). Also the html code is quite messy.

Otherwise - jquery datepicker uses a `class` ("datepicker" in most cases) to trigger it while yours uses and `id`. And `id` has to be unique on page. And since you want multiple instances you cannot give them same id as that will mess up the triggers.

You will have to produce an unique id for each instance.

Comment: can you please see the page by downloading the Zip   4shared.com/file/ZQy2A3DU/DateTime.html